# Python re.finditer(): concisely detect "A or :B or C:D"

Tags: python, regex, iteration

I am looking for a regexp that returns only three matched groups for the string "**A   :B C:D**"
where A,B,C,D are words examples (\w+)
The following Python code prints unwanted (None,None).

I just want ('A',None) (None,'B') and ('C','D') using one regexp (No added python code for filtering).

```
for m in re.compile(r'(?:(\w+)|)(?:(?::)(\w+)|)').finditer('A :B C:D'):
    print m.groups()
```

Answer (score 4):

This might do the trick:

```
(?=[\w:])(\w*)(?::(\w*))?
```

`(\w*)(?::(\w*))?` describes the structure you want, but it has a problem that it also matches empty string; thus we have to assure that there is at least one non-space character at the start (which will get matched by the greedy operators), and the lookahead at the start does it.

Edit: wrong paste :)

Comment: almost perfect! I just forgot to tell you that the ":" should not match. So I am using:(?=(?:\w|:\w))(?:(\w+)|)(?::(\w+))? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it. I'd probably write that condition as (?=:?\w), but now we're talking personal style :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

print([m.groups() for m in re.finditer(
    r'''(?x)               # verbose mode
        (\w+)?             # match zero-or-more \w's
        (?: :|\s)          # match (non-groupingly) a colon or a space 
        (\w+ (?:\s|\Z))?   # match zero-or-more \w's followed by a space or EOL
        ''',
    'A :B C:D')])
```

yields

```
[('A', None), (None, 'B '), ('C', 'D')]
```

Comment: I did not say that only 1 space may separate tokens. finditer should skip them. Take a better string as "A   :B     C:D   :   ".